# I have the alias of my keystore, but not the password

Tags: android, react-native, keystore, android-keystore

I've started working on an app after another developer which left.
When i try to build the app i'm facing

```
> Task :app:packageReleaseBundle FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:packageReleaseBundle'.
> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: jarsignerfailed with     exit code 1 :
  jarsigner error: java.lang.RuntimeException: keystore load: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
```

I have the keystore file, i have the alias, but i don't have the storePassword and keyPassword, even if i've been told they're the same

Do i have any way to fix this or is it a lost cause ?

Louis

Answer (score 1):

Password makes sure you're the app owner, not any other who has keystore to prevent harming the app.

If you cannot correct the storePassword & keyPassword, you won't able to sign it and upload with the same package name on Play Store.